# powershell hashtable.containsValue returns false, but looping the values gets a match?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

So I'm trying to create a function in powershell that nests all the groups a user is member of in ad. I map the groups into a hashtable, with the common name from AD as the value.

This goes well, and the function returns a hashtable containing all my groups. but when I query it using 
`$group = "IT-Avd"
    $groups.ContainsValue($group)`

### It returns false -- but when I loop over the values and do the same comparison, I do get a match! what's going on??

```
function get-groupmemberships ($workDN){
    $ADobj = [ADSI]"LDAP://$workDN"     
    foreach ($currGroup in $ADobj.memberOf.Value){
        if (!($currGroup -eq $null)){
            #Write-Host "displayN:" $grpDetails.Name " | dn:" $currGroup " | "
            if(!$groups.ContainsKey($currGroup)){
                $grpDetails = [ADSI]"LDAP://$currGroup"
                $groups.Add($currGroup,$grpDetails.Name)
                #Write-Host "Adding new pair, " $grpDetails.Name " | " $currGroup
                get-groupmembership $currGroup
            }
        }
    }
    return $groups
}

function get-DN ($SAMToFetch){
    $strFilter = "(samAccountName=$SAMToFetch)"
    $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
    $objPath = $objSearcher.FindOne()
    if($objPath){
        $objFound = $objPath.GetDirectoryEntry()
        $objDN = $objFound.distinguishedName
        return $objDN}
    else{ 
        return $false
    }
}

$groups = @{}   
write-host "Start search:",(Get-Date -Format T),",",(get-Date -format fff)
$group = "IT-Avd"
$memberOf = get-GroupMemberships (get-DN jslonsetteig)
$groups.ContainsValue($group)
foreach( $val in $groups.Values){if ($val -eq $group){Write-Host $val "<--It does seem to be there..."}}

write-host "End search:",(Get-Date -Format T),",",(get-Date -format fff)`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ContainsValue` is using a linear search of the hashtable so you're losing the benefit of the O(1) search the hashtable normally offers.  You might try creating another hashtable where the common name is the key instead.  Then you would use `ContainsKey` or just attempt the access by name and see if the result is not $null.

BTW one reason for the difference is that when you pass `$group` to `ContainsValue`, PowerShell does nothing in the way of type coercion since that method parameter is type `object`.  However when it executes `$val -eq $group`, PowerShell will potentially do lots of work to coerce `$group` to `$val`'s type.  Now while it may appear that `$group` is a string already, there are some psobject wrapping bugs that may be coming into play here (just a guess though).  What happens if you try `$groups.ContainsValue('IT-Avd')`?

You might also examine the type stored in the hashtable e.g.:

```
$groups.Values | Get-Member
```

Comment: is there's something about the comparer impl getting changed at times too from CI to CS? some bug? That might just affect keys though...

Comment: Ah yes, PowerShell's typical case-insensitivity doesn't come into play with ContainsValue() - that's up to the impl of ContainsValue and I'm pretty sure that would be case-sensistive.

Comment: well, I'm not quite sure what solved it; but when looking at it after getting some sleep, I got it working...

Comment: `function get-groupmemberships ($workDN){
 if($workDN){
  $ADobj = [ADSI]"LDAP://$workDN"
  foreach ($currGroup in $ADobj.memberOf.Value){
   if (!($currGroup -eq $null)){
    if(!$groups.ContainsKey($currGroup)){
     $grpDetails = [ADSI]"LDAP://$currGroup"
     $groups.Add($currGroup.toString(),$grpDetails.Name.toString())
     get-groupmemberships $currGroup
    }
   }
  }
  return $groups
 }
 else{
  return $false
 }  
}`

Comment: `function get-DN ($SAMToFetch){
 $strFilter = "(samAccountName=$SAMToFetch)"
 $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
 $objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
 $objPath = $objSearcher.FindOne()
 if($objPath){
  $objFound = $objPath.GetDirectoryEntry()
  $objDN = $objFound.distinguishedName
  return $objDN}
 else{
  return $false
 }
}`

Comment: aslo, `toString()` seems to be my new best friend